# Warning: require(/wp-includes/load.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream

Tags: php, wordpress

I uninstalled the W3 Total Cache plugin and added the WP Super Cache; however, the second plugin didn't get activated. I believe it was due to some W3 Total Cache files still showing on my blog and I went into FTP to remove them. Now I'm getting the below error message:

```
Warning: require(/wp-includes/load.php) [function.require]: failed to open 
stream: No such file or directory in /wp-settings.php on line 21

Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required 
'/wp-includes/load.php' in /wp-settings.php on line 21
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be a permission issue with those particular files.  You may want to try resetting the permissions, or overwriting the files in wp-includes with those from a fresh install of the same WP version.

Answer (score 0):

If you have uninstalled your wp-cache using the wordpress admin, you should also delete the wp-cache folders in your server under /wp-content/plugins/...[i forgot the folder name] that was auto generated by the plugin, and if still doesn't work, try to delete your .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

The first time I upload **Wordpress** to Server. I have the same issuse.
The problem because of I copy **.htaccess** from local to server

I fixed By change the url in .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```